# .Contains() on 2 properties in EF Code First

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

Is it possible to make a query on two differents properties in a Where()? For exemple, I want to fetch all my users that have "Robert G" in their FirstName ans LastName properties. If I do :

```
var contacts = _session.All<Contact>()
    .Where(x => x.IsActive
                && (x.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(q.ToLower())
                    || x.LastName.ToLower().Contains(q.ToLower())));
```

I will get no result for "Robert G" since FirstName contains "Robert" and LastName "Gambonni".

I also thought about making a new property FullName wich is only a Getter but then I have to load them all before since my property is not in the DB.

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It sounds like someone has bad data in their model :-) Is "Robert G" a valid FirstName? LastName? If not, don't allow it, then don't bother to look.

Comment: Or is this a more general question of: How to query a computed value without requiring extra model loads? e.g. `(FirstName + " " + LastName).Contains("Robert G")`, where FistName and LastName might be "Robert" and "Gambonni" for a particular record ..

Comment: it's for making an autocomplete for a big list of contacts so it will be easier for the customer to find the contact if he can enter both the first name and the last name to filter the possibilities

Comment: Another approach (besides the computed form) is to *split up* the user input, e.g. "FirstName LastName", and then use *each part* in the search for the applicable field. Of course "FirstOrLastName" also needs to be considered.

Comment: if you split, u ll have problems with middle name. i have co workers with 4 names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
var contacts = _session.All<Contact>()
    .Where(x => x.IsActive
                && ((x.FirstName.ToLower() + " " + x.LastName.ToLower()).Contains(q.ToLower())));
```

Comment: it was obvious... I need a break! Thanks for the quick reply!